# Google Drive API promise doesn't return at all when called from an AWS Lambda function (but works fine locally)

Tags: google-drive-api

We are calling the Google Drive API v3 (with OAuth2 authorisation) to list files on the drive. That works fine when run locally from my Mac, but if the function is deployed to AWS Lambda and invoked from there, the call just never returns. I expect a promise to resolve or reject, but that promise never returns, not in .then or .catch or .finally.

The parameters passed to the call locally and in the Lambda are exactly the same. The only difference I can see is the Lambda runs on Node 10.17 and local runs on Node 10.15. 
EDIT: Locally I have updated to Node 10.17 - the problem remains the same.

When I look a bit deeper in the API code, eventually the API calls a common apirequest.js file that calls the Google OAuth2 client .request() method. There too, locally and in the Lambda, the parameters are identical. This client .request() call returns a promise that never resolves nor rejects from the Lambda. When run locally, it resolves as expected.

Below are the parameters as passed to the OAuth2 client.

```
{
url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files',
method: 'GET',
paramsSerializer: [Function],
headers:
    { 
        'x-goog-api-client': 'gdcl/3.1.1 gl-node/10.17.0',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip',
        'User-Agent': 'google-api-nodejs-client/3.1.1 (gzip)' 
    },
params:
    {
        pageSize: 200,
        fields: 'nextPageToken, files(name, id, parents)',
        q:
        'mimeType="application/vnd.google-apps.folder" and trashed=false',
        supportsAllDrives: true,
        supportsTeamDrives: true,
        includeItemsFromAllDrives: true,
        driveId: '0AOWo32MbqS8pUk9PVA',
        corpora: 'drive'
    },
validateStatus: [Function],
retry: true
}
```

Any help, tips or ideas are very welcome :-)

Thanks

EDIT
The code to call the api added below

```
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            try {
                return googleDrive.files.list(
                    {
                        pageSize: 200,
                        fields: 'nextPageToken, files(name, id, parents)',
                        q: 'mimeType="application/vnd.google-apps.folder" and trashed=false',
                        supportsAllDrives: true,
                        includeItemsFromAllDrives: true,
                        driveId: config.googleDrive.sharedDriveId,
                        corpora: 'drive',
                    },
                    (err, results) => {
                        if (err) {
                            reject(`Drive error: ${err.message}`);
                        }

                        // Go through all results and do stuff ...... 

                        resolve({
                            driveFolders: results,
                        });
                    }
                );
            } catch (error) {
                logger.error('Error while calling google drive list: ' + error.message);
            }

        });
```

Comment: Could you provide the code you are using in your Lambda function? It would help for troubleshooting the issue.

Comment: @albertovielma I have added the actual call, thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting nothing when running your code in the Lambda function because it is not waiting for your response to come and it keeps running synchronously.

Change the syntax of your Lamda function to `async/await` way to be able to run the Lamda asynchrony. And then try this code:

```js
// with the async syntax you will be able to wait for the response to come
module.exports.init =  async function (){
  // Do your oAuth process as normal before calling the API
  const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', oauth2Client});
  //Notice how Im waiting for the response to come
  const pro2 = await waitForResult(drive);
  console.log(pro2);
} 

// This function will do the Promise flow and then return the value 
// from the promise to the init function 
function waitForResult(drive){
  return new  Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try{
      return drive.files.list(
        {
          pageSize: 10
        },
        (err, results) => {
          if(err) reject(`Drive error: ${err.message}`);
          resolve(results);
        })
    } catch(error) {
      console.log(error);
    }   
  });
}
```

### Notice

This is a test function I built, try it and then when you feel comfortable with the syntax,  adapt it to your code.

### Docs

Check these docs for more info:

- [async funtion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)
- [google-api-nodejs-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client#google-apis-nodejs-client)

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks for that. You are correct. The lambda continues but we are not waiting for the response. Locally the expected response was still logged, but ont he lambda the logging was recorded anymore (after the function has returned). Thanks :-)