# reading google spreadsheet data using node js not working..?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-sheets-api

I am using postman to call api. I am trying to read google spread sheet row using node js. Response is printing on console but its not returning to postman.

index.js file

```
app.post('/myapi/getClientkey',async (req, res) => {
  var response = null;
  console.log("Inside myapi");
  try {
    response = await spreadsheet.getRecord();
  } catch(err){

  }
  res.send(response);
});
```

spreadsheet.js

```
var config = require('./config.json');
var GoogleSpreadsheet = require('google-spreadsheet');
var creds = {
  client_email: config.client_email,
  private_key: config.private_key
}
var doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet(config.GOOGLE_SHEET_ID)
var sheet = null;


exports.getRecord =  async function () {

  console.log('Inside - getRecord');
  var name = null;
  var jsonObj = {};
  try {
          doc.useServiceAccountAuth(creds, async function (err) {
            // Get all of the rows from the spreadsheet.
            await doc.getRows(1, async function (err, rows) {
                if(rows != null){
                  var oneRow = rows[0];
                  name = oneRow.name;
                  console.log("name :"+name);
                  jsonObj.client_name = name.toString();
                }
              console.log(jsonObj);  
            });
          }); 
   }catch(err){
      console.log("err :"+err);
  }
  return jsonObj;
};
```

How to wait till response is returned from getRecord Function

Comment: Check the next answer on thread [Google Drive API promise doesn't return at all when called from an AWS Lambda function (but works fine locally)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59092228/6868879), it has mostly the same request. Let me know if it helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used promise call now it working.

```
exports.getRecord =  async function () {

  console.log('Inside - getRecord');
  var name = null;

  return new Promise( async function(resolve,reject){
      try {
              var jsonObj = {};
              doc.useServiceAccountAuth(creds, async function (err) {
                // Get all of the rows from the spreadsheet.
                await doc.getRows(1, async function (err, rows) {
                    if(rows != null){
                      var oneRow = rows[0];
                      name = oneRow.name;
                      console.log("name :"+name);
                      jsonObj.client_name = name.toString();
                    }
                  console.log(jsonObj);  
                  resolve(jsonObj);
                });
              }); 
       }catch(err){
          console.log("err :"+err);
          reject();
      }
    }); // end of promise
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Move `res.send(response);` inside `try` block and read about [how to return response from an async call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call).

Also `return jsonObj` should be inside `try` block

Comment: print error inside `catch` block. do you see any errors ?